# Transition duration does not work on page refresh

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

I am having a slight problem with my d3 transitions.

After a page refresh, the transition occurs instantaneously. I want the first transition after the page refresh to take 1 second like the others.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maurelius34/jhgzk7ox/2/)

Here's a snippet

```js
const name_ = d3.select('#name_container');

const M = name_
.append('text')
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('font-size', '2em')
    .text('M')
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .style('pointer-events', 'none');

const M_backboard = name_
.append('rect')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('width', 50)
    .attr('height', 50)
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        M.transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('opacity', 0);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        M.transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('opacity', 1);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id=name_container></svg>    
        <script src=index.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific with the issue you are seeing? For instance, what's the "first transition?"

Comment: Sure! I want the text 'M' to gradually become transparent when I mouseover. My problem seems to be that the d3 transition duration is not applied on the first mouseover, causing the 'M' to disappear instantly, but on the subsequent mouseovers the duration is applied, causing the 'M' to disappear gradually, as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `opacity` on the problem element is not initially set when the page loads so there's nothing to transition `from` to the `to`. If you set the `opacity` to 1 by default, you will get the expected results.

**EDIT** [Link to a forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gedzy2u/). Is this what you're going for?

Comment: This was exactly what I needed except I set the default opacity to one instead so that the letter appears when the page loads. I did not know that I needed to set the opacity beforehand. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The default value for an SVG element's opacity is `1`. That said, you don't need to previously set the opacity, *provided you use `selection.style()`* instead of `selection.attr()`.

Here is a simple demo. `style` will return `1` for the opacity, even if you never set it (internally, it uses `getComputedStyle`), while `attr` returns `null`:

```js
const c = d3.select("circle");
console.log(c.style("opacity"));
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(c.node()).opacity)
console.log(c.attr("opacity"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

All that being said, just use `style`:

```js
const name_ = d3.select('#name_container');

const M = name_
.append('text')
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('font-size', '2em')
    .text('M')
    .attr('fill', 'blue')
    .style('pointer-events', 'none');

const M_backboard = name_
.append('rect')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('width', 50)
    .attr('height', 50)
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        M.transition().duration(1000)
            .style('opacity', 0);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        M.transition().duration(1000)
            .style('opacity', 1);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id=name_container></svg>    
        <script src=index.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CSS?

```css
ele {
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}
ele:hover {
  //...
}
```